# Flutter - Remove the extra top of second appbar

Tags: flutter, space, appbar, scaffold, extra

I have a page: return Scaffold (appBar: appBar1...)
I have a package, in the package i have a pageA - return Scaffold (appBar: Appbar1)
. When i push a new screen from pageA - this navigate to the new page return Scaffold (appBar: appBar2...) - and has an issues: has the extra space above

How can i remove this.
Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcAK9.png)

Hi everyone,

I have a page: return Scaffold (appBar: appBar1...)
I have a package, in the package i have a pageA - return Scaffold (appBar: Appbar1)
. When i push a new screen from pageA - this navigate to the new page return Scaffold (appBar: appBar2...) - and has an issues: has the extra space above

How can i remove this.
Thanks
[

Comment: Can you provide your code in pageA and the another page that contains appBar2?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have 2 AppBar widgets underneath each other? I think the extra space is the top padding of the AppBar widget which is automatically calculated, normally you can access it using `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top`. However, I am not sure what happens when you have multiple AppBar widgets.